# Найти минимальный элемент в списке

Tags: c++, поиск, список

Требуется написать функцию для поиска минимального элемента в списке. Список задаю таким образом:

```
 template <typename T> class list   
{
    struct node       
   {
     T data;     
     node *next;
     node *prev; 
   };
 node *head;
 node *tail; 
 ...
}
```

Написал функцию, вроде бы компилируется без ошибок, но результата никакого не выводит. Не могу разобраться где ошибка.

```
 template <typename T> int list<T> :: seek_min()
{
  node *temp = head;
  int min = temp -> data;
  for (temp; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
  {
     if (temp->data < min)
     {
         min = temp -> data;
         temp = temp -> next;
     }
  }
 return min;
}
```

Comment: А куда вы ожидаете выдачу результата?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, в консоль

Comment: А вы не думали что надо оператор вывода воткнуть?

Comment: Да, я уже заметил эту оплошность.

Answer (score 1):

А что будет при достижении нового минимума? Вы перейдете в блок `if`, где благополучно перейдете к новому узлу... А потом - опять к новому узлу в третьей части заголовка цикла...

У вас явно лишний `temp = temp->next` в `if`.

И, кстати, просто `temp` в первой части заголовка `for` тоже не нужен. И - вы не проверяете, не пуст ли список, кстати говоря.

Comment: Убрал строку temp = temp->next  из цикла и все заработало. Спасибо!